# Zeppelin pyspark interpreter not able to submit application in YARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

Environment : AWS EMR emr-5.11.1 , Zeppelin  0.7.3 , Spark 2.2.1

**Problem : Zeppelin pyspark interpreter is not submitting jobs as applications in YARN**

As per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/zeppelin-considerations.html)  , i have done following changes , with no effect

1. set SPARK_HOME
2. added spark.executer.memory=5g , spark.cores.max ,
   master=yarn-client , spark.home in pyspark interpreter tab in zeppelin
3. added spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled = true in yarn-site.xml
4. Restarted interpreter and zeppelin process

**Please Help**

Comment: what are the errors? check logs and update the question with those. first try it yourself

Comment: There are no errors. I have checked zeppelin logs. Pyspark interpreter code eventually runs but no application in yarn is seen making me believe that zeppelin, yarn integration is not working and zeppelin interpreter is running on local mode

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

I have the same question, please upgrade to 0.8.0, the newest version solve that question.

### Solution 2

edit `$ZEPPELIN_HOME/conf/zeppelin-env.sh`, add export `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--num-executors 10 --driver-memory 8g --executor-memory 10g --executor-cores 4` ".

> if you don't have zeppelin-env.sh, please copy and rename zeppelin-env.sh.template to zeppelin-env.sh.

### Solution 3

edit `$SPARK_CONF_DIR/spark-defaults.conf` and modify what you want to add.

After that, restart your server.